# What are test cases in scheme and how do I use them?

Tags: scheme

I'm a complete beginner at scheme, and want to know what test cases are, or even do.
For example, if I wanted to write a test case for the negative root quadratic function I already coded and tested, how would I do it?

```
(define (quadnegative a b c)
(* (/ (+ (sqrt (-(square b) (* 4 a c))) b) 2 a) -1))
;Value: quadnegative

(quadnegative 1 3 -4)
;Value: -4
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by taking a look at the documentation of your interpreter for the specific details, for instance in Racket [here](http://docs.racket-lang.org/test-engine/index.html) is the testing framework available out of the box.

In essence, a test case will compare the *actual* value of an expression with the *expected* value - if they match, then the test succeeds. Here's a basic example of how this works in Racket (assuming that you've selected an appropriate language such as "Beginning Student"):

```
(define (add-one x)
  (+ 2 x)) ; an error!

(check-expect (* 21 2) 42)   ; test will succeed
(check-expect (add-one 1) 2) ; test will fail
```

The above will produce an output like this:

```
Ran 2 tests.
1 of the 2 tests failed.

No signature violations.

Check failures:
    Actual value 3 differs from 2, the expected value.
at line 5, column 0
```

For your tests, try to imagine test values of interest. Write some tests for inputs that return real values:

```
(check-expect (quadnegative 1 3 -4) -4)
```

And then, test for inputs that return imaginary values ... and so on. Try to be thorough in your tests, covering as many cases as possible, specially the unusual or "weird" cases that might result in "strange" output values.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful answer. I think I understand why test cases are run now, however, my version of scheme (MIT/GNU) does not use the syntax (check-expect), as it interprets it as an unbound variable

Comment: @user2789945 MIT/GNU Scheme doesn't provide `check-expect`. Start by googling for a good testing framework for MIT/GNU Scheme, and read its documentation. Ask your instructor/friends/etc. to see what tool they're using